# In Ruby, is it possible to have both Parent and child class in different Module

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to inherit a class which is in a separate module like Python allows? is there any other alternative that could be done without changing the structure drastically

File 1->

```
Module X
 Class Y
 end
end
```

File 2->

```
require relative 'path/to/File 1'
Module A
 Class B
 end
end
```

I want to inherit Y into B

Comment: That description is a bit vague. Could you show some code so it becomes more clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think I have answered your question, it seems. Just changed the module and class names after you gave the example.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible like this,Parent class Hello is in module `One` and child class Hi is in module `Two`.

```
module X
  class Y
    def call_me
      puts 'Hello Class'
    end
  end
end

module A
  class B < X::Y
    def call_me
      puts 'Hi Class'
    end
  end
end

A::B.new.call_me
```

output

```
Hi Class
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to inherit a class which is in a separate module like Python allows?

Classes aren't "in modules", so the "module" part of your question is actually irrelevant. The rest of your question essentially boils down to "Is it possible to inherit a class", which is possible.

*Constants* can be namespaces within modules, but that does not create any relationship whatsoever between the class and the module. In your example, the class referenced by the constant `Y` is *not* in the module referenced by the constant `X` and the class referenced by the constant `B` is *not* in the module referenced by the constant `A`.

The *constant* `Y` is namespaced inside the module referenced by the constant `X`, but that only creates a relationship between the *constant* and the module, not between the *class referenced by* the constant and the module.

You can prove the fact that there is no relationship easily by simply assigning the class to a different variable:

```rb
foo = X::Y

class A::B < foo; end
```

Note: please don't let the default value of `Class#name` fool you. The default value of `Class#name` is *indeed* the full path of the first constant that the class is assigned to, *even if* you remove that constant again later:

```
module M
  class C; end
end

module A
  B = M::C
end

M::C = nil
M.send(:remove_const, :C)
M = nil
self.class.send(:remove_const, :M)

foo = A::B

A::B = nil
A.send(:remove_const, :B)
A = nil
self.class.send(:remove_const, :A)

# *None* of the constants exist anymore.

foo.name
#=> 'M::C'

# The `Class#name` property still stays the path of the very first constant
```